# How to read multiple txt files - Python

Tags: python, automation, txt

I'm new with python and need to read these files from a directory.

```
MHBK_Trade_20210924_8387_20211007113214.txt
MHBK_TradeCash_20210924_8387_20211007113214.txt
MHEU_Trade_20210924_6144_20211007113525.txt
MHEU_TradeCash_20210924_6144_20211007113525.tx
Trade_20210924_7190_20211007113353.txt
TradeCash_20210924_7190_20211007113353.txt
```

I'm doing this way to read the files.

But this way every time I have to inform the complete name of the file. I would like to read only the first part, because this never changes.

```
def findmefile(directory, containsInFilename):
    entity_filenames = {}
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if containsInFilename in file:
            entity_filenames[re.findall("(.*?)_", file)[0]] = file
    return entity_filenames


# Get the core Murex file names
MHItradefiles = findmefile(CoreMurexFilesLoc, "Trade_20210924_7190_20211007113353.txt")
# MHItradeCashfiles = findmefile("TradeCash_", CoreMurexFilesLoc)
# MHEUtradefiles = findmefile("MHEU_Trade_", CoreMurexFilesLoc)
# MHEUtradeCashfiles = findmefile("MHEU_TradeCash_", CoreMurexFilesLoc)

MHItradefiles = pd.read_csv(
    CoreMurexFilesLoc + "\\" + "Trade_20210924_7190_20211007113353.txt", delimiter="|"
)

print(MHItradefiles)
```

I would like to know if it is possible to read these files from the first part as they are from different entities. Is this possible?

I need the values of a specific column, can I get the value by column name or by its index. The txt file is delimited by | ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first making a list of filenames in the folder.

```
from glob import glob
import os

files = glob(CoreMurexFilesLoc + '\\*')
```

Then you can check wether an individual file exists in the folder: `CoreMurexFilesLoc + "\\Trade_20210924_7190_20211007113353.txt" in files`

Or you can retrieve all filenames that start with a certain string:

```
MHItradeCashfiles = [i for i in files if os.path.basename(i).startswith('TradeCash_')] # or [i for i in files if 'TradeCash_' in i]
```